How do I queue jobs to Dagster?
I'm in the process of learning Dagster and I setup a project using dagster project scaffold --name my-dagster-project
I have Fast API running on localhost:8000, dagster running on localhost:3000.
I have set up an API endpoint to queue jobs to Dagster. This endpoint calls dagster_instance.create_run() where I pass in my job. I see this creates a new run on the dagster instance running on localhost:3000 but it's just stuck in Not Started.
I am able to run the jobs via job.execute_in_process and execute_job but I need the jobs to be queued on Dagster and automatically run as and when resources are available.
Dagster setup
@op
def sample_op():
  ....

@job
def sample_job():
  ....

defs = Definitions(
    assets=all_assets,
    jobs=[sample_job]
)

@repository
def my_repository():
    return [sample_job]

API endpoint-
dagster_instance = DagsterInstance.get()
dagster_instance.create_run(sample_job)

Am I missing something? My dagster.yaml is empty for now.
